# Setting defaultValue of HTML Text input field in Chrome VS IE9

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer-9

If I have the following HTML

```
    <input type="text" name="Text1" value="MyText" id="Text1"/>
```

If I after the page run the following javascript code

```
var text = document.getElementById("Text1");
text.defaultValue = "i am default value";
```

which sets the defaultValue of the input field I get two different reactions depending on the browser.
In IE9, the value is not changed, but default value is changed, which is actually the expected behaviour.
In Chrome (and Firefox) both the value and defaultValue are changed. WHY?
However if I run this JavaScript

```
var text = document.getElementById("Text1");
text.value = text.value; // No functional change, however triggers something in the DOM
text.defaultValue = "i am default value";
```

then it works as expected, that is it is only the defaultValue that is changed in Chrome

Any ideas on why and how to make Chrome (and Firefox) run as IE9 does?

Comment: *Any ideas on why and how to make Chrome (and Firefox) run as IE9 does?* -- A stack overflow first?

Comment: Didn't you just give an answer yourself? Loop through all the text fields and do that a=a thing. You said then it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`defaultValue` is generally the value of an element *until a user interacts with that element*. Once the user interacts with the element, the `value` property will not change when the `defaultValue` property is changed. When the defaultValue property is changed *prior to user interaction*, then most browsers will update the value property of the element. This behavior may not be consistent among browsers.